# remove the "and" between two affiliations in RevTeX 4.1

Tags: revtex

In this MWE:

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps,prl,twocolumn, showpacs ,groupedaddress,nobibnotes]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{author1$^1$, author2$^2$}
\affiliation{$^1$Department A}
\affiliation{$^2$Department B}

\maketitle
hello....
\end{document}
```

There is the word 'and' after 'department A'. I don't want it. How to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class uses `\andname\space`, so you can redefine `\andname` (usually expanding to “and” to gobble the space

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps,prl,twocolumn, showpacs ,groupedaddress,nobibnotes]{revtex4-1}

\renewcommand{\andname}{\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{author1$^1$, author2$^2$}
\affiliation{$^1$Department A}
\affiliation{$^2$Department B}

\maketitle
hello....
\end{document}
```

[image]